# TemplateDoesNotExist at / customer/index.html Request Method

Tags: python, django, conda, plotly-dash, miniconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ1Br.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4mvx.png)i get the error of Template does not exist # [[[e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16PJO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSKFa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/795HN.png)

this is my urls
when i run i get the error emplateDoesNotExist at / customer/index.html Request Method

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static 
from customer.views import Index, About

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('about/', About.as_view(), name='about'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Templates settings in settings.py should look like this

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": ["templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And your urls.py in your deliver1 folder should look like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("the-name-of-your-app.urls")),
]
```

I don't have a lot of experience with class-based views. However you can try this to see if works for you

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "customer/index.html", {})
```

Your urls.py in your customer folder will look like this

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

so any error you encouter, let me know

Comment: it still gives me the same error

Comment: Post your settings.py, and views.py and make sure your template folder is in your project root folder and not app

Comment: edited, views.py is there also template folder is in the root folder

Comment: thanks, still receive the error .. if i ever used dashplotly can be the cause?